# awk how to set parameter $2 become $b?

Tags: awk

In a Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#grep()
#{
#grep -q
#}

if [[ -z $1 ]];
then
  echo "usage: pkill -signal process name "
fi

if [[ -z $2 ]];
then
  echo "error: not enough parameters "
  exit
fi    

kill9="9"
kill15="15"

if [ $1 -eq $kill9 ]
then
  set "9" 
else
  set "15"
fi

ARRAY=(
  `ps -ef|grep $2 |grep -v grep|awk '{print \$2}'`
)

pkill()
{
  PIDTODIE=${2}
  for i in ${ARRAY[@]} ;do kill $1  $i;done
}

pkill $1 $2
```

Is it possible to assign in `awk`, `$2` so that it becomes `$b`? Because `$2` is a Bash parameter and gives me conflicts. Also the `\$2` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set variables in `awk` from the shell like so:

```
$ somevar=4
$ echo | awk -v my_var="$somevar" '{print "My var is " my_var}'
My var is 4
```

#### References

- [Can we use shell variables in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786777/can-we-use-shell-variables-in-awk)

Comment: which of [those categories](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) do you fit in? `;-)` (notice how your code nicely matches the _code injection_ vulnerability example I give in my answer there).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - thank you, I hadn't had the time to read through your Q&A yet (that's on my weekend reading list, though I'll bump it up to the top now 8-)). I'd never seen those variables quoted when being passed into `awk` before and hadn't realized that they too required quoting there. That code snippet was a copy/paste from a SO Q&A that I referenced, BTW. I'll edit that one as well. I'm that proficient w/ AWK.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - ah the example had `my_var=4` and an example further down that included `my_var="$some_other"`, so it was all my bad.